# Difference between decompiling and executing Java code

Tags: java, android, jvm, bufferedreader, reverse-engineering

As the question states is there any main difference between the process of decompiling code and executing. I know that decompiling uses reflection, and at some point used buffered reader or some type of reader, as Oracle has documented the structure of class binary files. When executing code normally, does it also use reflection in both android and java too.

If this is the case then it should be the case that if a decompiler was unsuccessful then the code doesn't run either (as they follow the same procedure) ?

Unless when executing code it only get's the information about the method called and not the whole class ?

I also noticed that something that can't be compiled can still run normally and decompiled to if manually edited.

```
class A extends A {...} //will run without any problem if manually edited
```

EDIT1:
Recently whilst trying something i got this result from the decompiled code but code failed to run as the code was like this

```
private static String voidFunction() {
    final int a = -1;
    final int b = a * -1;
    int c = (int)Math.pow(a, b);
    c *= new Random().nextInt(200);
    (new short[4])[0] = 48;
    true; // code on it's own
    -1; //missing return statement
}
```

Comment: You're asking the difference between how a decompiler decompiles and how a VM executes code? Does it even matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried a simple test and was able to easily create an application which could not be decompiled with any decompiler because of the nature of how Java application works, but the application run's perfectly fine on all OS's. On the other hand If a hacker or analyzer knows the method I used can easily create a decompiler to crack even this application.

So to answer my own question decompilers and running application takes different paths otherwise the application would never have run. I'm surprised their is nothing about this on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

They both work on the intermediary bytecode, but are surely completely different processes. Decompiling would take the bytecode from class files and attempt to recontruct plain text java source code. The virtual machine executes the bytecode by compiling it at runtime to machine level code that the computer can process. Therefore, they share the same source material, bytecode, but have completely different motivations and processes. Decompiling moves away from the machine level towards human programmers and compiling moves further away from the human programmer towards the machine.

There is a helpful explanation of these processes and bytecode at the start of [David Eck's free Java text](http://math.hws.edu/eck/)

Comment: whilst trying out something i got the decompiler to decompile successfully (random output though) but failed to execute

Comment: Decompiling only has to take bytecode back to source code text, so runtime exceptions may not be discovered. Executing takes the bytecode to machine code and runs the life cycle of events so runtime exceptions will be found.

Comment: actually in one case i had NullPointer on the decompiler but invalid tag index error in execution. Although if I'm not mistaken NullPointer is a run time exception and definitely has nothing to do with reading from buffer

Comment: Not certain, but I think you will find the Nullpointer is probably not from your code but from the execution of the decompiler. The decompiler is itself a program being executed.